# Select first record from each group in a table based on a state column switching between 0 and 1 using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have a table that looks like this:

| date_time | id | name | ip | ping_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-26 14:00 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-26 13:00 | 2 | Sonic | 2.2.2.2 | 1 |
| 2021-08-26 14:05 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-26 14:10 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 0 |
| 2021-08-26 14:15 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 0 |
| 2021-08-26 14:20 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 |

What I would like to do is, for a particular id (for example Mario), get the 1st occurrence of each state change which is the **ping_result** column.

**What I've tried**

I thought about using a common table expression and have been looking into the PARTITION BY clause. I thought if I could get the partition by clause to count up and reset when the **ping_result** column changes state, that would generate me a row number and then I could select from the CTE where the row_num is 1.  That intermediate CTE table would look like this:

| date_time | id | name | ip | ping_result | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-26 14:00 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-26 13:00 | 2 | Sonic | 2.2.2.2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-08-26 14:05 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-08-26 14:10 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-08-26 14:15 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-08-26 14:20 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 | 1 |

My SQL currently looks something like this (which obviously doesn't do what I want) because the partition by doesn't reset on the ping result field:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ping_result ORDER BY [date_time] DESC) AS row_num
    FROM [table] where id = 1 
)
    
select * from cte WHERE row_num = 1
```

**Expected Output**

The expected output I would like, should look like this:

| date_time | id | name | ip | ping_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-26 14:00 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-26 14:10 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 0 |
| 2021-08-26 14:20 | 1 | Mario | 1.1.1.1 | 1 |

Comment: Look into a construct making use of [lag()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks @allmhuran. Yes, it was the LAG function that I needed.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `LAG()` on `ping_result` and compare with current value

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, LAG(ping_result) OVER (ORDER BY [date_time]) AS prev_ping_result
    FROM [table] where id = 1 
)
    
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  prev_ping_result IS NULL
OR     prev_ping_result  <> ping_result
```

Comment: Thank you @Squirrel.  I have never heard come across the LAG function before but that produces the exact output I needed.